# Using ffmpeg merge two videos with xfade transition, but failed

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex_script "[0:a]atrim=0:0[a0];[0:v]split[v000][v010];[1:a]atrim=0:[a1];[1:v]split[v100][v110];[v000]trim=0:0[v001];[v010]trim=0:[v011t];[v011t]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v011];[v100]trim=0:0[v101];[v110]trim=0:[v111t];[v111t]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v111];[v011][v101]xfade=duration=1:transition=smoothleft[vt0];[v001][vt0][v111]concat=n=3[outv];[a0][a1]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map [outv] -map [outa] -look_ahead 0 -ac 2 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -profile:v high -preset:v veryfast -keyint_min 72 -g 72 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 3000k -minrate 3000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 6000k -b:a 128k -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -fflags +genpts -y ffmpeg-xfade-concat.mp4
```

Comment: Remove `-hide_banner`, run command again, provide the complete log.

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting an error:

## Failed to set value for option 'filter_complex_script'

`-filter_complex_script` accepts a text file. The text file contains the filtergraph. But your filtergraph is in the command itself.

Either move the filtergraph into a text file and use `-filter_complex_script filters.txt`, or change `-filter_complex_script` to `-filter_complex`.